# couldn't get the cookie nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I set a cookie with,

```
router.get("/addCartToCookie", function(req, res) {
  let options = {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    httpOnly: true, 
  };

  let cartData = {
    name: "test cookie",
    slug: slugify("test cookie"),
    productPictures: "K6B4dzGjN-teal.jpeg",
    price: 200,
    description: "testing cookies",
    quantity: 7,
  };

  // Set cookie
  res.cookie("cartName", cartData, options); 
  res.send("Cart Added to Cookie");
});
```

Which perfectly sets a cookie named "cartName". But once I try to get the cookie,
It shows "cartName" is undefined.

Get Cookie Code:

```
router.get("/getCartFromCookie", function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.cookies["cartName"]);
  console.log(req.cookies);
});
```

I tried console logging the cookies but it also shows undefined.

Comment: Fixed. The issue was I dint import and use cookie-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, the optimized way of handling cookies is by using `cookie-parser` dependency for express.

```bash
$ npm install cookie-parser
```

Then you could easily fetch your cookies using `req.cookies` or `req.signedCookies` property like below:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)

  // Your cart cookie
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies.cartName)
})

app.listen(8080);
```

##### References:

1. https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser
2. http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't show all your code, but I assume you're using the [cookie-parser middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) to access the cookies directly on the request object. If not, start by adding cookie-parser and go from there.

For your cookie reading issue, be aware that you can't send and read cookies on the same request. You need one request to set the cookie and another to read the cookie.

```
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import {inspect} from 'util';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router()
router.use(cookieParser())
app.use(router);

const port = 3000

router.get('/setcookie', (req, res) =>{
  res.cookie('testCookie', 'magic content');
  res.send("set the cookie");
})

router.get('/readCookie', (req, res) =>{
  res.send('your cookies: ' + inspect(req.cookies['testCookie']));
  console.log(req.cookies);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```